# How to find out a laptop is 32 or 64 bit using DOS?

Tags: cpu, ms-dos, freedos

I bought one HP laptop, it only came up with DOS installed.

How do I get to know its 32 bit or 64 bit?

I am sure HP guys can help me out but I want to know a way to find it out via DOS.

**More info:**

1. When I switch on my laptop it shows c prompt `C:\>` not BIOS.
2. It has 15 core, i5 8th Gen Intel Processor

[image]

Comment: You tagged this windows but your title asks about DOS. Those are different things. Windows has not run on top of DOS since windows 95.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The DOS operating system is 16 bit. How old/new is your laptop? You may be thinking its DOS while it really is not.

Comment: @Cadmos - Your edit would significantly change the author's question, based on an assumption.  HP does not sell laptops with MS-DOS.

Comment: DOS has almost no useful tools inside so you can't use it to find out information about the architecture. OTOH you almost can't find any 32-bit computers nowadays. All the CPUs produced by Intel and AMD in the last decade are 64-bit ones except a few early Atom CPUs, so you don't need to check

Comment: @Ramhound author wrote about HP, not me. I can't just delete his "assumption" based on yours.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound here. MS-DOS is so likely not being referred here. Its far more likely that OP sees a BIOS/text screen, possibly stating something like: "Bootloader missing." and just assumes this is DOS. For that reason, I referred back to the previous edit.

Comment: But they do sell laptops with FreeDOS, no? Both my Asus laptop and my Dell came with FreeDOS as the default OS. The OP never specified *MS*-DOS if you want to get pedantic.

Comment: To clear the speculation, please take a photo of the screen showing what you are referring to... It's quite possible that you are stuck in the BIOS (with no OS to load). Model numbers are also quite helpful to determine such information.

Comment: @Hennes that's so funny. I can't believe I did this mistake.

Comment: Please clarify with an [edit] to your question: *How do I get to know its 32 bit or 64 bit?* Are you asking about the bitness of the CPU or the operating system?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator you are not joking, right? I was ROFL though. I am asking bitness of CPU/machine/laptop. It is a blank machine without what would suit it how would jump to bitness of OS. First I need to know system's bitness and accordingly OS's. `Bitness` :)

Comment: @paul I'm not joking, though I'm glad the comment made you laugh. However, since you do not explicitly state that you're asking about the CPU, one must *assume* that is what you mean. However reasonable such an assumption may be, it still requires putting words in your mouth, an act that violates site standards. We need you, the OP, to remove the ambiguity from your question.

Comment: @Ramhound author uploaded a screenshot, so it was clearly your personal assumption that author "assumed" that he had DOS pre-installed on his laptop ..

Comment: @Cadmos - FreeDOS != MS-DOS.  I had no doubt the machine came with a DOS variation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CPU Identifier](http://web.inter.nl.net/hcc/J.Steunebrink/chkcpu.htm) which is a DOS utility that displays information about your CPU architecture in DOS. Download it to a media device and transfer it in your laptop.

Use it in verbose mode for getting the maximum of the information you might need about your CPU

`CHKCPU /V` will print on your screen something like this

[image]

If it does not show whether the CPU supports 64-bit or not, you can see its Vendor and model and search on Google for factory specifications.